# How to Stop Reading From a BufferedReader when sending an Object in Java?

Tags: java

I´m writing a java program that sends an object converted to a byte array through a socket. The client has to read all the bytes and translate it back to a Java Object. However I´m having my program stuck on a `read()` inside the loop where I read all bytes until I find a -1.

I've read the docs and it says that the `read()` method return a -1 when reaching the end of the stream, but this is not working.

Heres my code:
Method for sending an object:

```
Socket socket;
BufferedReader input;
DataOutputStream output;
boolean connectionOpen;  //Just for you to know the types of the attributes of my class
 public void sendResponse(Object obj) throws IOException{

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    try {
      out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
      out.writeObject(obj);
      byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();


      output.write(yourBytes);

    } finally {
      try {
        if (out != null) {
          out.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        // ignore close exception
      }
      try {
        bos.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        // ignore close exception
      }
    }  


}
```

Method For reading the bytes. (This is where my code gets stuck)

```
public Email getMail(int id) throws Exception{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[50000];
    Email result;
    try{
        this.outToServer.writeBytes("MAIL "+id+"\n");
        String response = inFromServer.readLine();
        String[] data = response.split(" ");
        int code = Integer.parseInt(data[0]); 
        if(code==500){
            throw new Exception("Error en servidor Pop4. Servidor respondio: "+response);
        }
        int current =  inFromServer.read();
                int i = 0;

        while(current!=-1){

            bytes[i]=(byte) current;
            i++;
            current= inFromServer.read();
        }
        //Convertimos el arreglo de bytes a un objeto Email
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInput in = null;
        try {
          in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
          result = (Email) in.readObject(); 

        } finally {
          try {
            bis.close();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
          }
          try {
            if (in != null) {
              in.close();
            }
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore close exception
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }            
    }

    catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
    }
    return result;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are quite right that `InputStream.read()` returns -1 when it cannot transfer any bytes because it has reached the end of the stream.  However, nothing in what you presented gives me any reason to think that condition will be satisfied.

End of stream corresponds to a condition in which it is certain that no more bytes ever will be received from the stream.  That is not at all the same thing as there being no more bytes available at any given time.  If the sender indeed has nothing further to say for the remaining life of the connection, then it should *close* the `OutputStream` for its end of the connection.  After it does so, the reader should detect end-of-stream.  You presented no evidence that you do that.

If the sender is not ready to close the stream, then you need to devise a different way for the receiver to know when to stop reading.  That implies some kind of application-layer protocol on top of the stream. One of the simplest of such protocols involves sending messages consisting of a fixed-width byte-count followed by the specified number of bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I´ll implement an application layer protocol then.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read one object at a time directly from the socket.

```
final ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

public void sendMessage(Object obj) {
    out.writeObject(obj);
    out.reset();
    out.flush();
}

final ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

public Object readMessage() {
    return in.readObject();
}
```

In short, you need to know when you should stop reading or use a stream which does.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. But I would like to know how to do it with bytes just for the sake of learning more deeply how the buffer behaves. If you could give some insights on the bytes that would be great! Thanks again.

Comment: @PabloEstrada you need to know how long the data is.  For binary data, you would usually put the length of data before it so you know how much to read.

Comment: @PabloEstrada The byte array streams are completely pointless here. They are just a waste of time and space. There is nothing useful to be learnt by using them, except not to use them.